# How to get highest possible number between 2 numbers under one condition - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic

I am looking for an efficient/simplest way to find highest possible number between 2 numbers under 2 condition. The condition being that the numbers should be added or decremented as specified by a parameter and that every number after the preceding cannot be greater than adjacent numbers by more than one

**Example**

If given numbers 1 and 5 with a = 7, (1) -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 6 -> (5). Every number is not greater by its adjacent number by more than a factor of 1. Given the range 1 and 5 and with count = 7, the highest possible number should be 7. I apologize if the question isn't explained properly.

I am looking for something mathematically or in java

Comment: Note that this does not always have a solution (assuming integers).

Comment: how so? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: this question should be closed as too broad.

Comment: Could you also add your code attempts?

Comment: Sure - given numbers 1 and 10 with a = 5.